Intuitive explanation of the backward Kolmogorov equation?
I work with diffusion problems, and I feel I have a reasonably good practical understanding of how the Fokker-Planck equation (aka the forward Kolmogorov equation)
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big( a(t, y) \, p \big) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \big( b^2(t, y) \, p \big), $$
describes the development of the probability density, $p(t,y)$, for an ensemble of solutions to the SDE
$$ \mathrm{d} X = a(X, t) \, \mathrm{d}t + b(X, t) \, \mathrm{d}W, $$
given an initial condition, and $a$ and $b$ being "moderately smooth functions" (Kloeden & Platen, 1992, p. 37).
My problem is in understanding exactly what the backward Kolmogorov equation can tell me. According to Kloeden & Platen, the transition density of the SDE, $p(s, x; t, y)$ (which describes the probability density of a solution going from position $x$ at time $s$, to position $y$ at time $t$) obeys both the Fokker-Planck equation, and also the backward Kolmogorov equation,
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial s} = - a(s,x) \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{2} b^2(s,x) \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}, \;\;\;\;\; (t,y)\;\mathrm{fixed}.$$
Does this mean that if I know that a solution to the SDE had a value $y$ at a time $t$, I can obtain a probability distribution for values $x$ at earlier times, $s < t$? And this would be in the sense that given the observation at time and position $(y,t)$, the probability distribution of positions at time $s$ would be $p(s,x; t,y)$, not in the "anti-diffusion" sense where a broad distribution becomes more narrow as we go backward in time?
And is it straightforward to solve this numerically, or do I have to somehow take into account in the time derivative that I want to go ``backwards'' in time towards smaller s?
Also, any link or reference to a nice, readable example, ideally with a numerical example, would be very much appreciated. I feel the Fokker-Planck equation is fairly well explained here and there in the applied literature, while the backward equation mostly shows up in mathematics books that are both very terse and dense with specialised terminology. A straightforward explanation in terms of diffusing ink molecules in water, or something along those lines, is what am looking for.

The KBE is directly associated to the monumental Feynman-Kac formula. I suggest reading on that to obtain a good view.

I guess part of my problem is that I just find it very hard work to read mathematical literature, and I have a feeling (or a hope?) that it should be possible to achieve a "practical" or "applied" understanding if I don't care about all the details and definitions and the full generality of the problems. But I'll take your suggestion, and try to make an effort with Feynman-Kac, like a serious adult.

@Snoop Do you have a recommendation of book, paper or similar, for reading about Feynman-Kac?

Shreve is introductory - it is designed for finance background people, but you may find the connection with your research interesting. There is a chapter on the matter.

That would be chapter 6, "Connections with partial differential equations"? Doesn't look too bad, I'll give it a go.

A side note: The "anti-diffusion" is different from KBE, as you know already know, and it turns out that "anti-diffusion" is also a diffusion! This, however, cannot be used to find the densities at earlier times because the equation itself required them (or more precisely, the Stein score function associated to them). In modern applications, it turns out that score functions can be effectively trained using deep neural networks, and many state-of-the-art image/video generation models are based on this idea.

Thanks for the link. This is interesting stuff. It feels like anti-diffusion should be very tricky due to something with information and entropy and so on, but I haven't looked much at it.

After reading a bit, I think I came up with a reasonable answer. And if this isn't the correct answer, then by Cunningham's law, it will at least be more likely than before that someone else will supply a better answer.
For an SDE
$$ dX = a(X, t) dt + b(X, t) dW_t, $$
there is a transition density, $p(y, s; x, t)$, describing the probability density for a solution that has value $y$ at time $s$ to have value $x$ at time $t$, with $s \leq t$. This transition density, which we will call $p$ for short, obeys the forward and backward Kolmogorov equations, provided that $a$ and $b$ are "moderately smooth functions" (Kloeden & Platen, p. 37 ).
Just for completeness, the forward equation is
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big( a(x, t) \, p \big) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \big( b^2(x, t) \, p \big), \;\;\;\textrm{keeping $y,s$ fixed},$$
and the backward equation is
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial s} = - a(y, s) \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} - \frac{1}{2} b(y, s)^2 \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial y^2}, \;\;\;\textrm{keeping $x, t$ fixed}. $$
The point of the backward equation is that if we observe that a solution has value $x$, at time $t$, it can tell us the distribution of most likely values $y$, at an earlier time $s$. Or to put it in practical terms, if we observe an oil spill or a life raft or whatever, we can find the most likely locations it came from, at some earlier time, given the observation and the advection and diffusion describing the problem.
To illustrate the backward equation, I will use an SDE that I will call the forward SDE,
$$ dX = \big(v + K'(X, t) \big)\, dt + \sqrt{2K(X, t)}\, dW_t, $$
where $K(x, t)$ is the diffusivity, $K' = \partial K / \partial x$, and $v$ is a constant advection velocity. It is left as an exercise to the reader to verify that the forward Kolmogorov equation in this case becomes the advection-diffusion equation.
Additionally, I will use an SDE which I will call the backward SDE (see Eq. (20) in Shah et al, 2007),
$$ dX = \big(-v + K'(X, t) \big)\, dt + \sqrt{2K(X, t)}\, dW_t. $$
Basically this equation has the backward Kolmogorov equation for the forward SDE as it's forward Kolmogorov equation, so that modelling the backward SDE forwards in time is equivalent to modelling the forwards SDE backwards in time. If that makes sense.
To try to make this a bit more concrete, I will do three different numerical demos. For all three, I will assume that we have made an observation of a distribution of solutions, uniformly distributed on the interval $[x_0 - \Delta x, x_0 + \Delta x]$, and I will be asking where these particles most likely came from, given that their motion (forwards in time) is controlled by the forward SDE. I will do the following:

Starting out with a uniform distribution $[x_0 - \Delta x, x_0 + \Delta x]$, at time $t$, I will use the backward SDE to find the distribution at the earlier time $s$.
Starting out with a very wide, uniform distribution at time $s$, I will use the forward SDE to model the transport until the later time $t$, and then keep only those solutions that ended up inside the interval $[x_0 - \Delta x, x_0 + \Delta x]$ at time $t$, and look at their
initial distribution at time $s$.
Starting with $$p(y,s; x,t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl} 1 / 2\Delta x & \mathrm{if} & x \in [x_0 - \Delta x, x_0 + \Delta x] \\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise} \end{array} \right., $$ I will solve the backward Kolmogorov equation numerically (using finite differences) to find the distribution of initial positions.

The results are shown in the figure below, where the observed "final" distribution is shown is a continuous black line, and the "initial distribution" obtained by three different methods are also shown, as well as the diffusivity (which was variable in space, but constant in time). The drift velocity was constant, $v=0.02$, and the initial and final times were $s=0$ and $t=4$.

The code to produce the plot can be found in a jupyter notebook here: https://github.com/nordam/backward-kolmogorov/blob/main/Backward.ipynb
Some observations, to maybe clarify things a bit:

The transition density describes the probability of moving from one location to another, under the influence of the forward SDE. With diffusion alone ($v=0$), the probability of going from x to y is the same as the probability of going from y to x.  With advection, which introduces a bias in one direction, the advection velocity must be reversed to get the same probability.
Going backwards, we do not find what the distribution looked like at an earlier time (so-called anti-diffusion), but rather the probability density for a particle at a given position to end up at the observed final position/interval.
In implementing the numerical solver for the backward Kolmogorov equation, I used a normal finite difference discretisation. The only unusual step I took with respect to going backwards in time was that I wrote the iterative equation on the form $$p(t_i, ...) = p(t_{i+1}, ...) + \Delta t \times (...),$$ instead of $$p(t_{i+1}, ...) = p(t_i, ...) + \Delta t \times (...)$$ as is usual for a normal forwards PDE.

